# DataFrame: Function Not Applying -- "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'month_name' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, function, dataframe, variable-assignment, apply

Below is my code:

[image]

This is the error I receive:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'month_name' referenced before assignment`

Comment: See [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elif month == 12:
    month_name == "Dec"
```

Notice how this case (and the default one at the end) is slightly different from the previous 11 cases?  When `month` is 12, you *compare* `month_name` to `Dec`, rather than assign it - which fails because `month_name` has not previously been assigned any value.

Comment: apologies, I don't quite understand

Comment: `==` is not the same operation as `=`.